# Python 3 wsgi - json response

Tags: python, json, response, uwsgi, wsgi

I use `uwsgi` for serving my web content and it works well when it comes to usual html pages:

```
return [b'<html><head></head><body>Hello, world!</body></html>']
```

But when I want to return `json`:

```
headers = [('content-type', 'application/json')]
test = json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
test1 = bytearray(test, 'utf8')

start_response('200 OK', headers)
return [test1]
```

the webserver returns nothing...there is no error, just empty response body... anybody could explain me why?

thanks and greetings!

Comment: Could you add more information please, for example traceback?

Comment: hey, i updated my question and added my full code. There is no error, but just an empty response body..

Comment: am i the first one with this issue?

Answer (score 4):

```
test = json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])    
test1 = bytes(test, 'utf-8') # or test.encode('utf-8')
start_response('200 OK', headers)
return [test1]
```

Answer (score 3):

If that is your full code then you forgot to import the json library

```
import json
def application(environ, start_response):
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'application/json')]
    start_response('200 OK', headers)
    test = json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
    test1 = test.encode('utf-8')      
    return [test1]
```

Answer (score 0):

for testing use this

json.dumps({"newdata":"test"})